# Why does NO2 react with HCl ? What is the mechanism of the reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I found the following reaction given in a certain book:
 $$\ce{2NO2 + 4HCl -> 2NOCl + Cl2 + H2O}$$

I cannot think of any reason why an acidic oxide like $\ce{NO2}$ will react with an acid like $\ce{HCl}$.

So, why will they react? And, what will be the mechanism of the reaction?

Comment: It is a redox reaction. One compound is a strong oxidant; another can reduce it, albeit not very willingly. So it goes.

Comment: What do you mean acidic oxide?

Comment: @NMJD acidic oxides are oxides that on hydrolysis gives acid and on reacting with base gives salt. Basic salt on the other hand gives base on hydrolysis.

Comment: Your equation is not balanced.

Comment: @NilayGhosh - I'm aware. I wanted user39139 to answer the question; some students misunderstand "acid oxide" and assume it should act as an acid in the way of HNO3 or HCl. I wanted to see if that was at the root of this question, since otherwise the answer just lies in redox potentials (which has already been suggested). If this misunderstanding persists, that answer might not help OP. I suppose to be clearer I should have said, "Can you define what you mean by 'acid oxide'"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is a typical redox where nitrogen dioxide is an oxidising agent and hydrochloric is a mild reducing agent as Ivan noted.

The reaction proceed in two phases:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{NO2 + 2HCl ->[\Delta] NO + Cl2 + H2O}   & \tag{R1}\\
\end{align}
$$

Now some nitrogen monoxide react with water to form nitrosyl chloride.

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Cl2 + 2NO -> 2NOCl}   & \tag{R2}\\
\end{align}
$$

Finally, we get our main reaction

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{2NO2 + 4HCl -> 2NO + 2Cl2 + 2H2O}   & \tag{R1*2}\\
\ce{2NO2 + 4HCl -> (2NO + Cl2) + Cl2 + 2H2O}\\
\ce{2NO2 + 4HCl -> 2NOCl + 2H2O + Cl2}  & \tag{R3}\\
\end{align}
$$